# Double-quoted string not working when I run an .au3 file in the command prompt

Tags: cmd, autoit

My script writes a file path for uploading a file. I ran the same script in two different ways. It runs properly in the first way, but fails in the second way.

```
$sPath="C:\ProgramData\Cisco Systems\Screen and Clean\ISB7K_2K\Configuration\op_and_settings_config.bin"

ControlSetText("[TITLE:Open]", "", "[ID:1148]", $sPath)
```

- First way: When I ran the script using the Script Editor; it sent/wrote the proper file path.
- Second way: When I called the same script from cmd.exe, it sent/ wrote only the file name (not complete file path). How can I fix this?

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. From what I see, I assume compiling the script will solve the problem.

Comment: There are some spaces in the path. Maybe you have to quote it. $sPath='"C:\ProgramData\Cisco Systems\Screen and Clean\ISB7K_2K\Configuration\op_and_settings_config.bin"'

Comment: @Xenobiologist thanks ; I used single quote instead of double quote & it worked

Comment: Nope.
Changing double quotes to single quotes does absolutely nothing in this code. It was something else you changed.

Comment: I did R&D and found out that if we use single quote in autoit....it wraps the content, besides I didn't do any other change

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of Xenobiologist's comment, when you have a quoted string in the command line (your cmd.exe scenario), you need to wrap those in single quotes; the interface can throw a hissy fit (pardon the technical term) if you try to pass a string with single quotes.

Use `$sPath='"C:\ProgramData\Cisco Systems\Screen and Clean\ISB7K_2K\Configuration\op_and_settings_config.bin"'`